# What are the possible values for the securityInfo domicile field?

Tags: yodlee

I see '1' for real accounts and 'US' in DAG accounts. Is there a well-defined enumeration for the possible values and their meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domicile value is populated based on the country the security belongs to. Right now there is no documentation around the possible values and their meanings. Thanks for bringing this up , we will have the mapping documented on Yodlee's developer portal soon.